# How i can my textbox include 'id' in ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have this table which I accessed it with ajax.

```
      Name       Qty  Price   subtotal    exchange        
123   Pepsi       2   5.000   10.000    | [txtbox1] |  [button]
221   Toblerone   1   16.000  16.000    | [txtbox2] |  [button]
```

I want.. if i type in txtbox1 = 1 and i click button, the qty will be 1.

furthermore, in each txtbox have different id which the id is its expired date.
Here's the code :

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"<?php echo base_url()?>pembelian/cek_notabeli",
    dataType : 'json',
    data:{'nonota':nonota}
    }).done(function(obj){
      if(obj != '-'){
            var tbl=$("<table/>").attr("class","table");
            var head = "<thead></thead><tbody>";
            $("#div1").append(tbl);
            for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
            {
                var tr="<tr>";
                var td1="<td>"+obj[i]["idbnb"]+"</td>";
                var td2="<td>"+obj[i]["nama"]+"</td>";
                var td3="<td>"+obj[i]["jumlah_barang"]+"</td>";
                var td4="<td>"+obj[i]["hpp"]+"</td>";
                var td5="<td>"+obj[i]["subTotal"]+"</td>";
                var td6="<td>
   <input type='text' class='jumtur' name='jumtur'/></td>";

                var row = $('.jumtur').attr('id', obj[i]["exp"]); <-- expired date
                var td7="<td><button class='btn btn-info'>Retur</button></td>";
                var hid= "<td>
   <input type='hidden' class='jumtur1' name='jumtur'/></td>";
                var tr2="</tr>";

                var id =$('.jumtur1').attr("id",obj[i]["idbarang"]);

               $(".table").append(tr+td1+td2+td3+td4+td5+td6+hid+td7); 
            }  
            $(".table").append(head);
        }
```

How i can my textbox include id in ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var tbl=$("<table/>").attr("class","table");
var head = "<thead></thead><tbody>";
$("#div1").append(tbl);
for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    var tr="<tr>";
    var td1="<td>Text1</td>";
    var td2="<td>Text2</td>";
    var td3="<td>Text3</td>";
    var td4="<td>Text4</td>";
    var td5="<td>Text5</td>";
    var rowtxtid = i;
    var td6="<td><input id="+rowtxtid+" type='text' class='jumtur' name='jumtur'/></td>";                
    var td7="<td><button class='btn btn-info' rel=" + rowtxtid + ">Retur</button></td>";
    var hid= "<td><input type='hidden' class='jumtur1' name='jumtur'/></td>";
    var tr2="</tr>";

    var id =$('.jumtur1').attr("id",(10 + i));

    $(".table").append(tr+td1+td2+td3+td4+td5+td6+hid+td7); 
}  
$(".table").append(head);


$(".btn-info").click(function(){
    var temptxt = $(this).attr("rel");
    alert($("#" + temptxt).val());  
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BwD2H/)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the ids directly on the string:

```
if (obj != '-') {
    var tbl = $("<table/>").attr("class", "table");
    var head = "<thead></thead><tbody>";
    $("#div1").append(tbl);
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        var tr = "<tr>";
        var td1 = "<td>" + obj[i]["idbnb"] + "</td>";
        var td2 = "<td>" + obj[i]["nama"] + "</td>";
        var td3 = "<td>" + obj[i]["jumlah_barang"] + "</td>";
        var td4 = "<td>" + obj[i]["hpp"] + "</td>";
        var td5 = "<td>" + obj[i]["subTotal"] + "</td>";
        var td6 = "<td><input type='text' id='" + obj[i]["exp"] + "' class='jumtur' name='jumtur'/></td>";
        var td7 = "<td><button class='btn btn-info'>Retur</button></td>";
        var hid = "<td><input type='hidden' id='" + obj[i]["idbarang"] + "' class='jumtur1' name='jumtur'/></td>";
        var tr2 = "</tr>";

        $(".table").append(tr + td1 + td2 + td3 + td4 + td5 + td6 + hid + td7);
    }
    $(".table").append(head);
}
```